# Exposing Terraforms over REST API

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to expose terraform over REST API so that the external process can trigger "terraform apply" to create infrastructure. Are there any recommended ways of doing this?

Comment: This would be something you would expect Hashi to develop, and probably not something you would want to take on yourself. Terraform Cloud and Terraform Enterprise may be suitable alternatives for you. Alternatively, a pipeline would also achieve this, as those typically have REST APIs.

Comment: Thankyou. Jenkins does have a terraform plugin.

Answer (score 0):

HashiCorp has a guide [Running Terraform in Automation](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/development/running-terraform-in-automation) which covers some of the considerations and tradeoffs you'll need to make to run Terraform in an automated manner, regardless of what exactly is triggering the running of Terraform.

As mentioned in that guide, HashiCorp offers Terraform Cloud and Terraform Enterprise as ready-to-use solutions for running Terraform remotely via an HTTP API. Terraform Cloud and Terraform Enterprise implement those features using the same principles described in the guide. If you wish to build something similar yourself, you may also find it interesting to refer to the [API-driven Runs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/run/api.html) section of the Terraform Cloud documentation, to get an overview of how the Terraform Cloud API exposes the ability to run Terraform via an HTTP API.